# Unify error messages in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

When i work with json, if json not valid, i send errors in format:

```
error: { error: { obj.email: [{args: "", msg: "error.email"}] }  //1
```

But with json validators, i have a standart methods, which validate data (for example, if email present in database).
How to unify all methods, that send errors in json form (1)?

for example controller with action:

```
 implicit val loginReads: Reads[Login] = (
   (__ \ "email").read[String](email) and
   (__ \ "password").read[String]
 )(Login.apply _)


 def login() = Action { request =>
   request.body.asJson match {
     case Some(login) => login.validate[Login] fold (
       err => BadRequest(Json.toJson(Map("error" -> JsError.toFlatJson(err)))),
       result => if (!isPresentInDb(result.email)) {
         //how to handle error and send it as json error form: "error" -> JsError.toFlatJson(err) 

       } else {
         //success
       }            
     )

    case None => //bad request
   } 
 }

 //login class
 case class Login(email: String, password: String)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three options:

1. create objects that match what JsError.toFlatJson wants (a List of JsError?) and call it with them
2. create your own utility method that will take your own kind/type of validation error and produces the expected json structure
3. provide your own serialization of both JsErrors and your own error messages that has the json structure you would want